# Selenium File Upload Not Working in Azure Pipeline/ VM Machine

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, automated-tests, azure-pipelines

Hi I am Trying Achieve File upload Scenario My Test cases using selenium

Element I am Doing Actions On:-

```html
<input _ngcontent-swn-c63="" type="file" id="undefined" multiple="" accept=".gif, .xlsm, .zip, .xls,.xlsx, .pdf, .ppt, .pptx, .doc, .docx, .jpeg, .jpg, .png, .csv, .txt">
```

Selenium Script I am Using :-

```html
WebElement UploadElement=(new WebDriverWait(driver, BaseInitializer.defaultwaitTime)).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@type='file' and @id='undefined']")));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].style.display = 'block';", UploadElement);
UploadElement.sendKeys(newname.getAbsolutePath());
```

While the above piece of code is working in My Local Machine(Chrome browser). Same script is not working while running the code in Azures Pipeline. The File is not getting reflected in Upload Element. What may be the issue? Or I am missing something?

Comment: What is `newname.getAbsolutePath()` ? Is that the correct location in Azure as well  ?

Comment: Yes, I have kept the Files(That should be uploaded) in Project root Directory, And I have also Printed the Path in console and it is same as in Local.

Comment: Did you try to put some sleep ? I see that you are using WebDriverWait but still, and when it does not get uploaded in pipeline, is there any error  ?

Comment: That is the Weird part, The Function is not throwing any error but at the same time when I check the screen shot there is no file present in upload element.

Comment: Both of your local and VM are windows?

Comment: You have mentioned "And I have also Printed the Path in console and it is same as in Local." how it could be same? Both should be different as both are separate machines.

Comment: Yes, Both are Windows Machine

Comment: @NandanA Same- Meaning Not Exactly the Same but the File Path is correct in both Local and VM

Comment: @AutomationTester Did you find any solution for this? I'm trying to upload file via .sendKeys in azure pipeline , but file not found although I see the file in the path